# Compare two csv files to ouput the matches Python

Tags: python, list, csv, compare, match

I have a csv file called "organs.csv" and another csv file with lots of data. I'm comparing them to get matches among them. The latter file doesn't have any particular format so I don't know which column has data about organs. I've tried the below code to get matches but it has two issues.

1. If csv2 has an organ in two columns, it appends to the list twice.
2. If a row doesn't have any organ, it just ignores it.

I'd like it to do the following:

1. If a row has an organ, skip to the next one (limit one organ per row)
2. If no organ is found, print something like "-"

code:

```
import csv
filename = "file.csv"
complist, orglist = [], []
fileA = open(filename, "rb")
reader = csv.reader(fileA, delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    for row_str in row:
        complist.append(row_str)
with open("organs.csv", "rb") as fileB:
    reader = csv.reader(fileB, delimiter='\n')
    for row in reader:
        orglist += row
        orglist = [x.lower() for x in orglist]
org = open ("organ_matches.txt", "wb")
org_writer = csv.writer(org)
for s in complist:
    for xs in orglist:
        if xs in s:
            print >> org, xs
org.close()
orgfile = open ("organ_matches.txt" , "r")
organ = orgfile.read()
organ = organ.split("\n")
organ = ",".join (organ)
organ = organ.split(",")
orgfile.close()
print organ
```

csv1:

```
forearm
leg
abdomen
```

csv2:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4
data1,forearm biopsy,tissue,cell
data2,leg injury,tissue in leg,cell9
data4,data,tissue4,cell6
```

It now prints:

```
['forearm','leg','leg']
```

Desired output:

```
['forearm','leg','-']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I have *eventually* used a *list comprehension* `*` to store organ names,
next I have looped over the 2nd to last line of the other file,
using a `stop` auxiliary variable to exit from two loops at once
(this is the bit that you didn't catch...).

#### The Code MkI

```
organs = [line.strip() for line in file('uno.csv')]
matches = []
for line in [line for line in file('due.csv')][1:]:
    stop = 0
    matches.append('-')
    for item in line.split(','):
        if stop : break
        for organ in organs:
            if organ in item:
                matches[-1] = organ
                stop = 1

print matches
```

#### Alternate Take

Here I've removed the inelegant auxiliary variable and used a trickier,
more obscure but more pleasant (to me...) approach

```
organs = [line.strip() for line in file('uno.csv')]

matches = []
for line in [line for line in file('due.csv')][1:]:
    match = '-'
    for item in line.split(','):
        if match != '-' : break
        for organ in organs:
            if organ in item:
                match = organ
    matches.append(match)

print matches
```

#### The output

```
['forearm', 'leg', '-']
```

---

`*` **Edit** It seems that the order of `organs` is important to you, so I changed the data structure used to store the names of the organs from a set to a list.

---

**Edit #2**

#### More Precisely

From the OP it is clear that, for each line of `due.csv`, it is needed only one match.  What it's not clear to me (in retrospect) is how to choose only one match.

I think that we want to scan the `item`s in each `line` from left to right and stop scanning when we find a match, so far so good... but what if an `item` matches more than one `organ`?

My current code always complete the `for` loop on `organs`, so the match that is appended is the last match in the order defined in `uno.csv`...

If the requested match were the first one, my code must be modified adding a `break` to the `for` loop on `organs`

```
        for organ in organs:
            if organ in item:
                match = organ
                break
```

That said, the choice is yours...

Comment: Thank you for your response but I just gave csv2 as an example. It doesn't need to be in the second last column.

Comment: @amy Why do you think that my code only matches in the second last column? For each line, each item is compared against the members of organs until a match is found...

Comment: It gives me ['-','-','-']

Comment: The FIRST code in my answer was copied and pasted from my terminal without any editing, I've copied and pasted the example data that you showed in your question in two files, `uno.csv` and `due.csv`, I'm using python 2.7 on debian testing and... it gives me `['forearm', 'leg', '-']`, I swear! Seriously, I cannot imagine what could have gone wrong.

Comment: :D I've copied and pasted in my Python editor. I haven't changed anything except for the filenames and it gives me just '-'s. I updated my question with a screenshot. I'm using Python 2.7 too. Maybe its a mistake on my side.

Comment: Ah! My bad! There was an issue with upper and lower case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following code works generally, ignoring the header line of csv2:

```
import csv
orglist = []
organ_matches = []

# Generate list of organs
with open('organs.csv', 'rb') as f_org:

    csv_f = csv.reader(f_org)

    for row in csv_f:
        orglist.append(row[0])

# Convert to a set
set_org = set(orglist)

# Read csv2 file
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as f_tbl:

    # Open output file to write to
    with open('organ_matches.txt', 'wb') as f_out:

        csv_f = csv.reader(f_tbl)
        csv_f.next() # Ignore header

        for row in csv_f:

            set_row = set(' '.join(row).split(' ')) # Combine list elements and separate words

            # Find common words with organs list and select only one
            if set_row.intersection(set_org):
                organ_match = list(set_row.intersection(set_org))[0]
            else:
                organ_match = '-'

            organ_matches.append(organ_match)
            f_out.write(organ_match + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to loop over your data file (complist) once, and can remove the extra nested loop.

So that your:

```html
for s in complist:
    for xs in orglist:
        if xs in s:
            print >> org, xs
```

becomes:

```html
for s in complist:
    if s in orglist:
        print >> org, s
    else:
        print >> org, '-'
```

Comment: To the spiteful soul who hit-and-run downvoted without comment, please post your reasoning if you haven't moved on to spread your spite further.